# Convert to Spoken Binary

Tags: code-golf, number, binary

## Introduction

In the video [the best way to count](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDDaEVcwIJM), binary is proposed as the best system of counting numbers. Along with this argument is a proposal on how to say numbers in this system. First, we give names to each "double power of two", \$2^{2^n}\$ for each \$n\$.

```
number = symbol = spoken
============================
2^0    = 1      = "one"
2^1    = 2      = "two"
2^2    = 4      = "four"
2^4    = H      = "hex"
2^8    = B      = "byte"
2^16   = S      = "short"
2^32   = I      = "int"
2^64   = L      = "long"
2^128  = O      = "overlong"
2^256  = P      = "byteplex"
```

Then, to get from [a number to its spoken binary](https://youtu.be/rDDaEVcwIJM?si=ZFzrA-zpjOc1OAXY&t=3587), we

1. Take its (big-endian) bit string and break off bits from the end equal to the number of zeros in the largest double power of two less than or equal to the number.
2. Use the name for the corresponding double power of two in the middle, and recursively name the left and right parts through the same procedure. If the left part is one, it is not spoken, and if the right part is zero, it is not spoken.

This system is similar to how we normally read numbers: 2004 -> 2 "thousand" 004 -> "two thousand four".

For example, 44 in binary is `101100`.
Split at four bits from the end and insert "hex", meaning \$2^4\$: `10` "hex" `1100`.
`10` becomes "two" and `1100` splits into `11` "four" `00`, or "two one four".
So the final number is "two hex two one four" or `2H214` in symbols (note that this is not the recommended way of writing numbers, just speaking).

As a longer example, we have one thousand:

```
1111101000
11 B 11101000
2 1 B 1110 H 1000
2 1 B 11 4 10 H 10 4 00
2 1 B 2 1 4 2 H 2 4
```

## Challenge

Your program must take a positive integer \$n\$ as input and output the string of symbols for the spoken binary of that number.

While numbers under \$2^{512}\$ are expressible in this system, you only need to handle integers **up to and including** \$2^{32}\$ = `I`, and as such, do not need to consider `L`, `O`, or `P`.

Standard loopholes are forbidden.
As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest program wins.

## Example Input and Output

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 21
4 -> 4
5 -> 41
6 -> 42
7 -> 421
8 -> 24
9 -> 241
10 -> 242
11 -> 2421
12 -> 214
25 -> H241
44 -> 2H214
100 -> 42H4
1000 -> 21B2142H24
4294967295 -> 21421H21421B21421H21421S21421H21421B21421H21421
4294967296 -> I
```

Comment: May the input be taken as a list/string of binary digits?

Comment: No, you must take the integer as a (decimal) integer. Only if your language somehow does not have integers, you may take the the number as a string of its decimal digits.

Comment: So if `12` is `214` and `8` is `24`, why is `4` not `14`?

Comment: "If the left part is one, it is not spoken, and if the right part is zero, it is not spoken."

Comment: I was actually looking for justification of the rule, but I worked out that not having the rule changes the problem into something else (all numbers can take the form ...242H242B242H242 and the value comes from inserting `1`s in the correct places).

Comment: Yeah. I was mostly just copying the  system in the linked video. It certainly does change how you'd have to program it.

Comment: Hi. Would you please consider adding a second different wording for *"Take its (big-endian) bit string and break off bits from the end equal to largest power of two that can split the bit string into two parts."*? I struggle to understand what is meant. What does "can split the bit string into two parts" mean? Looking at the example `101100`, how did you decide to split it into `10,1100` and not into `1,01100` or `101,100`?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I can guess that maybe "Find the largest power of 2 which has a symbol and is less than or equal to the number" could be it?

Comment: Did anyone point out yet that in C, ints are only at least 16 bits, longs are only at least 32 bits? at least 64 bits has the silly name long long. the fixed width types have the less unique names int32_t and so on.

Comment: @Stef the rationale behind that wording is that 101100 has 6 bits. The largest power of two less than that is 4. We break off 4 bits from the end. That's why 4 is the largest power of two that splits it into two parts. For 1010, it has 4 bits and 2 is the largest power of two that would split it into two parts. Let me know if there is a better way to explain that.

Comment: And if my explanation still doesn't make sense, the linked video may help. Although they do not use very precise words either, the visual is helpful.

Comment: Re: your earlier comment replying to noodle man: In most languages, integer numeric types are binary, not decimal.  That's why `x << 1` multiplies by 2, not 10.  Decimal is only used as a serialization format.  In a C function like `unsigned foo(unsigned x) { return x+5; }` there's nothing decimal going on, just binary integer math.  It's a pet peeve of mine when people describe numeric types as decimal or hex when they're not talking about I/O or source-code representations (literals).  (This is a real source of confusion in assembly-language beginner questions on SO.)

Comment: So AFAICT, what you really want to forbid is taking input as a string or list of base-2 digits.  In whole programs that take numeric input from the user, they can't require or take advantage of it already being a base-2 string.  Functions should take the number as a scalar numeric type, not digit-strings at all, unless a language makes that impossible (e.g. pure text processing like `sed` perhaps), and in that case it must not be in base 2.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's all stored as binary under the hood. That's why I put "decimal" in parentheses. While it's not actually being stored in decimal, in almost every language, the input will be written in decimal. This makes it a little bit easier for languages that have easier access to the bits of their numbers, because I wanted the question to take a pure number to its spoken binary, not a string of bits to the spoken words.

Comment: @Tbw Your explanation does make sense, thank you. My difficulty to understand right away was because of the two meanings of "powers of two": here we have numbers of the form `2^(2^k)` and it's unclear whether "the power of two" meant `2^k` or `2^(2^k)`. Also I hadn't noticed at first that the powers of two in the table were almost all of the form `2^(2^k)`. (I say "almost all" because there is also `2^0` in there)

Comment: The narrator of TBWTC approves :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>36</s> 29 bytes

```
BUḟ€0“24HBSI”s2jœr1ɗẎḊḢ$?€ɗƒU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9qZWxsef//QlXhuJ/igqww4oCcMjRIQlNJ4oCdczJqxZNyMcmX4bqO4biK4biiJD/igqzJl8aSVf///zEwMDA)

A full program that takes a single positive integer argument and prints the spoken binary form to STDOUT.

### Explanation

```
BUḟ€0“24HBSI”s2jœr1ɗẎḊḢ$?€ɗƒU⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
B                             # ‎⁡‎⁡Convert to binary
 U                            # ‎⁢‎⁢Reverse
  ḟ€0                         # ‎⁣Filter out 0 from each
     “24HBSI”             ɗƒ  # ‎⁤‎⁢⁢Starting with this, reduce using each character in "24HBSI" as the right argument in turn and the following:
             s2               # ‎⁢⁡- Split into pieces of length 2
                         €    # ‎⁢⁢- For each piece:
                     ḊḢ$?     # ‎⁢⁣  - If length 2 and the second part is non-empty:
               j              # ‎⁢⁤    - Join with the relevant character
                œr1           # ‎⁣⁡    - Trim 1s from the end
                    Ẏ         # ‎⁣⁢  - Else: join outer lists
                            U # ‎⁣⁣Reverse order of final string (and implicit smashing print)
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
≔⁻Ｉ⮌↨Ｎ²0θＦ24HBSI≔Ｅ⪪θ²⪫⮌ＥΦκ∨μ¬ν⎇∧ν⁼μ1ωμιθθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoIwEEX3nqLpaprUBIg7Vmg0YiIa8QIVqzaWAdqC8fS1EHXzNv//N1M9hKkaob3PrFV3hL3C3sJKWAcnOUhjJSxFQI5t74q@vkgDjJOEsUAa0cCOpbNbYwjQZLFdljll5CcTLZStVg66ccLJrlH4947pRmkXjE9ODgZqTorGAU7uszQozBsyvAJysu56oe1YoTEd8xcn9VRU7PvD0SgMl1jqfRxFkZ8P@gM) Link is to verbose version of code. Supports numbers from `1` to `18446744073709551615`. Explanation:

```
≔⁻Ｉ⮌↨Ｎ²0θ
```

Convert the input to a list of `1`s and empty strings according to the reverse of its binary representation.

```
Ｆ24HBSI
```

Loop over the additional possible "digits".

```
≔Ｅ⪪θ²⪫⮌ＥΦκ∨μ¬ν⎇∧ν⁼μ1ωμιθ
```

Group the existing digit blocks into pairs, then for each pair, create a new digit block by removing any second part if it is zero, or making it the empty string if it is one, switching the parts, and joining on the next digit.

```
θ
```

Output the final result.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>84 79</s> 77 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=6,y=1,u=2**2**--k)=>n<y?'':~k?f(n/u,k,2)+['24HBSI'[n<u||k]]+f(n%u,k):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBda4MwGIXv31/hzTCp8ePNUjtL00Kv7HUvnaxitWw6Le0cFcr@ustHYYOQ53DO4RDyUXwX1/Lyfv7yu/5YTVMtSccaGbNRIhskn83U8f2GynW3Gjeuu/xpNjXpwoE1jFMvc7lIt/udm3Wr4X5v8txT6ZNK6RKnsu@ufVsFbX8iB0DHXzsIXIPDswGC0BQwN0CIDTksLBFeTE9AYomAkVUcEB9KmXYVBXCzlOqmMNs81TZGkV1MjbYbuFWRygUInogkXvBk/tjhmJp7/0//tcwrd3AILtW5LcqKhOT16FHtksCj4eeJOeSN3dioPi6ryY1KOTJNNuaUTr8)

Your 2<sup>32</sup>-1 case seems wrong

Comment: You're right, I forgot the `B` layer. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 129 bytes

```r
\(x,`~`=paste0)Reduce(\(y,z)apply(matrix(y,2),2,\(w)gsub("^0*[1"~z~"]|0","",w[1]~z~w[2])),c(2,4,"H","B","S","I"),x%/%2^(63:0)%%2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7BSsNAEIZfZRlYmJGp3WyDSCE99FSP6jGb0BizUtCyZDckDRLwObxEwYfybVxpDx_D_D_MN59f7fxts58u2MXt74fBgffTPnOVD42ih-a5qxs0eOKRKudeT_hWhfYwxEATazbY04vvnhBKdZUnMI0TFO8KGID7PCni3ue6IOIaNacMu1htI4-ROyAe5FLqEm9Wa0VSaro8cl9XAf3ZWGOyTlNOlPpHsS5X0S0MjuRdezgGiyCvlRWLjZAeWIwsbCyjVPjGiQzMES6H5_k8_wA)

An R translation (more-or-less) of my Jelly answer. A function that takes a single positive integer and returns the spoken binary form as a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 42 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
l2l2Ḟ
WµÇ2*2*⁸d⁹jɗ×nJaƲ¹Ƈ)F$ÐLÇ»-ị“4HBSI12
```

A full program that accepts a positive integer and prints the spoken binary.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUwAs/9qZWxsef//bDJsMuG4ngpXwrXDhzIqMirigbhk4oG5asmXw5duSmHGssK5xocpRiTDkEzDh8K7LeG7i@KAnDRIQlNJMTL///8xMDAw)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/HKMfo4Y55XOGHth5uN9Iy0nrUuCPlUePOrJPTD0/P80o8tunQzmPtmm4qhyf4HG4/tFv34e7uRw1zTDycgj0Njf4/apj7cOe0Q0u4dA63ZwHFFWztFIBimpH//xvqKBjpKBjrKJjoKJjqKJjpKJjrKFjoKFjqKBgaADFQ3hCowAgoZ2ICEjMAccxAhDmYC@SbGFmaWJqZG1maIrHNAA).

#### How?

```
l2l2Ḟ - Link 1: integer, X -> floor(X log 2 log 2)
          Note when X = 1 l2l2 -> (-inf + nan j) and Ḟ takes the real part -> -inf

WµÇ2*2*⁸d⁹jɗ×nJaƲ¹Ƈ)F$ÐLÇ»-ị“4HBSI12 - Main Link: positive integer P
W                                    - wrap P in a list
                      ÐL             - apply while distinct:
                     $               -   last two links as a monad - f(Current):
 µ                 )                 -     for each {V in Current}:
  Ç                                  -       call Link 1 -> floor(V log 2 log 2)
   2*                                -       2 exponentiate {that}
     2*                              -       2 exponentiate {that}
                                               -> value of the digit to use, say D
       ⁸    ɗ                        -       last three links as a dyad - f(V, D):
         ⁹                           -         D
        d                            -         {V} div-mod {D}
          j                          -         join {that} with {D}
                Ʋ                    -       last four links as a monad - f(Parts=that):
              J                      -         indices {Parts} -> [1,2,3]
             n                       -         {Parts} not equal {that} (vectorises)
            ×                        -         {Parts} multiply {that} (vectorises)
               a                     -         {that} logical AND {Parts}
                 ¹Ƈ                  -       keep truthy values
                    F                -     flatten
                        Ç            - call Link 1 (vectorises)
                         »-          - max with -1 (convert -inf to -1)
                           ị“4HBSI12 - index into (1-based & modular) "4HBSI12"
                                     - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 115 bytes

```hs
p=[2^2^i|i<-[6,5..0]]
c=concat
f x=c[c[f y|y>1]++c[[l]|y>0]|(l,n,m)<-zip3"ISBH421"p$tail p++[1],y<-[mod x n`div`m]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9Pi4MwEMXv@RSD7EExFpOqXUH34MmeewwpldSyYf3HKku7@N3dJG3aUthL@L1582Ymn9X4VTfNsgw5o3u6l7PMApbgeLUKOUciF30nqgmd4JwLJtgJLvPlg3DfF4w1XHHIZ7fBHW69LPiVw9rZ7ooyosQZ3qZKNjD4PiMcX9TYtj/CGbrDUf4cWs6XtpId5DB8y24CNVpCnkMPM7gSQ@9BFsBUj5OoxnrkCN1ZZRgCcAkGhzge1kwV0xuvNVsjUiK6cazZGokWNrIxwlrveoANpUZYi4RG2hwhV3m3zR3EZqneWD7Skb6Glo8GEoZmc/lUMBtIoZpUp61HNI3SZEPT@LqAktK8xRPv/qm/jtA/3zoeR8sf)